# iOS views navigation issue

Tags: ios

I got A,B,C,D four views and A is the root view. A pushes to B, B pushes to C, C presents to D. And when C presents to D it'll firstly go back to B and then presents to D. Also, when D dismisses, it'll go back to B. Why?

Actually I want that it can present from C to D without go backing to B.

Update: I checked my code and there is no pop method triggered when C present to D but it just goes back to B and then presents to D. I tried to use push to jump to D, interestingly, the app crashed(I set All Objective-C Exception but didn't capture anything).

Comment: C presents to D or C pushes to D

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Too many lines of code><

Comment: How do u pushing views using segues? please share the code for presenting c on d

Comment: I just use presentViewController method

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you are presenting D from C, popTOViewController is calling thats why it is going back to B , because its in the navigation stack. Please check the code while going C to D.

Answer (score 0):

When you present D you first go back to that time your controller go back to B and then present D so you dismiss D so you can see controller B...

You can push D from C without go back...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but because of the design reason, I rewrote C view and now it seems ok.